# How to make my selenium code work faster?

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

The code fetches all the games available in fitgirl and makes a dictionary with the number of comments in each of the game. The comment fetching part requires selenium because it depends on their disqus service.
Can I somehow optimize the process?

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.common import exceptions
import requests

path = 'C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe'

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

info_dict = {}

for page_number in range(1, 31):

    url = f'https://fitgirl-repacks.site/all-my-repacks-a-z/?lcp_page0={page_number}#lcp_instance_0'

    response1 = requests.get(url)

    index_site = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response1.content, 'lxml')

    ul = index_site.find('ul', class_='lcp_catlist')
    for li in ul.children:
        site_url = li.a['href']
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
            driver.get(site_url)

            page_data = driver.page_source

            site = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_data, 'lxml')

            comment = site.find('span', class_='comments-link').a.string
            title = site.find('header', class_='entry-header').h1.string
            print(title + ' ' + comment)

            info_dict[title] = comment
        except exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException:
            print('pass')
        # driver.close()

driver.close()

print(info_dict)
```

Comment: My only suggestion is that the title doesn't need to be rendered by selenium in which case you could grab this using BS and only use selenium for comments. The comment variable you have gets the number of comments which is behind a pseudo element. Pseudo-elements are not within the DOM therefore BS can't parse it.

Comment: Optimizing is a broad topic. Have you profiled your code to see what parts are slowest? Do you have a target speed you would like to achieve?

Comment: @GregBurghardt optimized in the sense selenium is very very slow to fetch the data. I have about 30x30 data to fetch and one data takes 1 minute to fetch.

Comment: @AaronS So what to do about the comments?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the web sites running slow?

Comment: You're launching browsers inside the loop and not closing them for one thing.

Comment: @pguardiario I learned it the hard way :3 had 100 chrome instances in task manager

Comment: @GregBurghardt website isn't slow. Its the chrome instance selenium creates each time which is slowm af